# Error declaring function with arguments in cython

Tags: python, c++, function, cython

Figuring out a way of using python functions in c++, I came across python, I am writing a simple fibonacci function which adds n numbers from a particular index in to the given list l. I am a newbie to cython so the error might be trivial :). Please point out what is wrong:
from libcpp.list cimport list
from test import test_sum

```
cdef public long long gen_fibonacci(list[int] &l,int in,int  n):
    num = 3
    t1 = 0 
    t2 = 1
    nextTerm = 0
    i=1
    if ind==1:
        l.append(0)
        l.append(1)
        i=3
    if ind==2:
        l.append(1)
        i=2
    while i<n:
        nextTerm=t1+t2
        t1=t2
        t2=nextTerm
        if num>=ind:
            i=i+1
            l.append(nextTerm)
        num=num+1
    return test_sum(l)
```

Error:

```
cdef public long long gen_fibonacci(list[int] &l,int in,int  n):
                                                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

strat_plugin.pyx:4:53: Expected ')', found 'in'
```

compile command:

```
cython -2 strat_plugin.pyx
```

Comment: `in` is a Python keyword. Pick another name.

Comment: cool, thanks, the error msg is kind of useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change `in` into another word in the line:

```py
cdef public long long gen_fibonacci(list[int] &l,int in,int  n):`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you put 'in' instead of 'ind'. In addition 'in' is a keyword therefore reserved.

`cdef public long long gen_fibonacci(list[int] &l,int ind,int  n):
    num = 3`